# How come my Search Console report doesn't show position of a keyword?

Tags: google-search-console

From [some article](https://www.crazyegg.com/blog/unlock-not-provided-keywords/) I see a screenshot like this
[image]

in the table below, besides "clicks" and "impressions", there are also "position" and "CTR". However, in my account, I can only see "clicks" and "impressions".
[image]

Did I misconfigure something or did google hide the "position" metric?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to click the checkbox next to "Average position" for the column to show.
[image]